# Can't transfer variables to useMutation's function.( vue apollo, composition api, graphql )

Tags: graphql, vuejs3, apollo, vue-composition-api

I am working on a frontend program, the front end stack:
Vue3, Vue Router, apollo client. Vue apollo's composition api.

in my component's script:
I have a mutation like this.

```
const USER_MUTATION = gql`
    mutation deleteUser($username: String, $customer_id: String) {
        deleteUser (username: $username, customer_id: $customer_id) {
        customer_id 
    }
  }
`
```

then in my setup function, I have code like this.

```
setup() {
    const customer_id = ref(0)
    const username = ref('')

    const { mutate, onDone, onError } = useMutation(USER_MUTATION)

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log(customer_id.value);
        console.log(username.value);
        mutate({
            variables: {
                username: username.value,
                customer_id: customer_id.value 
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log("success");
        });
    }

    onDone((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    })

    onError((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }) 
 
}
```

I found I couldn't transfer the variables (username and customer_id) to the mutate(), when I try it.
I got the error:

```
ApolloError: Internal server error
    at new ApolloError (index.ts:89:1)
    at eval (QueryManager.ts:257:1)
    at both (asyncMap.ts:30:1)
    at eval (asyncMap.ts:19:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.then (asyncMap.ts:19:1)
    at Object.eval [as next] (asyncMap.ts:31:1)
    at notifySubscription (module.js:132:1)
    at onNotify (module.js:176:1)
    at SubscriptionObserver.next (module.js:225:1)
```

how should I do?
thank a lot.

I have tried run the useMutation, unless I hardcode the variables in USER_MUTATION definition, it can not works.

I hope someone can suggest a proper solution for me.

greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Can you look at your browsers network devtools? You are getting an error from the server - it should tell you what's wrong. If I were to guess, I'd say that maybe your customerId is a number, not a string, but that's a shot into the blue.

Comment: in backend's mutation module, the debug info prompts the args is null. so I am not sure whether the usage:        ``` mutate({
            variables: {
                username: username.value,
                customer_id: customer_id.value 
            }
        }) ```' is ok. maybe we can have other ways to transfer the customer_id and username to the mutation?   thank you very much and have a nice day!

Comment: I tried transfering the string directly in the mutate function:  ``` mutate({ variables: { username: "abc", customer_id: "225" } }) ```  it also doesn't work.

Comment: Please show the definition of the `deleteUser` query from your GraphQL schema.